# HTTP Error 500.31 - Failed to load ASP.NET Core runtime even after isntalling Hosting Bundle

Tags: reactjs, .net-core, deployment, .net-7.0, .net-runtime

I have an ASP.NET Core 7 API with front end on React.js. We recently migrated it to .NET 7 it was previously built on .NET 5.

[image]

I'm trying to deploy it on the production server where I have already installed .NET 7 hosting bundle along with previously deployed .NET 3, 5 and 6 for dependencies on other projects.

[image]

I have checked dotnet --info and all of these are listed there as well.

[image]

We have already tested this setup on dev server and faced no issues but when Im trying to test the app I'm getting

> HTTP Error 500.31 - Failed to load ASP.NET Core runtime. Common
> solutions to this issue : specified version of
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App was not found.

I have checked application logs in the event viewer and this is what Im getting there.

> Unable to locate application dependencies. Ensure that the versions of
> Microsoft.NetCore.App and Microsoft.AspNetCore.App targeted by the
> application are installed.     Process Id: 6828.     File Version:
> 17.0.23196.10. Description: IIS ASP.NET Core Module V2. Commit: 5a4c82ec57fadddef9ce841d608de5c7c8c74446

I'm badly stuck at what I have missed any help in this.